# can't able to delete selected item in a listView via context menu?

Tags: android, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to delete the selected item in listview through Context menu.

here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
EditText editText;
Button add;
ListView listView;
final DBFunctions db=new DBFunctions(MainActivity.this);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] values;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    values=db.getAlldata();
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = editText.getText().toString();
            if (!name.equals("")) {
                editText.setText("");
                long check = db.insertData(name);
                if (check < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in insert query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name + " inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                editText.setError("this field is empty");
            }
        }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int position=listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String data=values[position];                    //error line 
    Log.e("Value  ", data );
    Log.e("Position ", position+"" );
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.delete_name:
            long check=db.deleteData(data);
            if(check<0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error in query",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,data+" deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

when i run above code i get following error:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1
        at pack.madhan.listviewdemo.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:72)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2628)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3864)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
```

is it possible to delete selected item in listview via context menu ? 
please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found an answer

**Error Code:**

```
int position=listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
String data=values[position];
```

**Updated Code:**

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

String data=values[info.position];
```

where **info.position** gives the position of item in listView.
To refer [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html#AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo(android.view.View,%20int,%20long))

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logstack, your function listView.getSelectedItemPosition() returns -1.

```
int position=listView.getSelectedItemPosition();

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1
```

-1 is not a correct index, and is the cause of this OutOfBoundsException.

I've never tried to keep track of the latest element selected in a list, but you could do as follow :
Add a variable at the begining of your MainActivity to keep track of the selectedItem;

```
// First item of the list is selected by defaul to avoid out of bound
int selectedItem = 0;
```

And update this variable with the onItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
      selectedItem = id;
   }
});
```

Comment: if that line of code was wrong,could u tell me how can i get index of selected item in listView?

Comment: it doesn't works. every time it deletes the item at index[0].

Comment: Then it probably means that the onItemClickListener is never triggered.
Have you tried to log the position in the onItemClick to see if it's triggered and see if it sets it to the right position ?
If it's not triggered you should investigate your code and find why it's never triggered.

Comment: i have updated my code with solution. thanks for your involvement

Comment: Actually it might be my fault, seems like i mixed up position and id.
Anyhow, I've edited the code, but glad you found the proper solution.